# Where does the mustache go during the transformation?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

In the past late 2000s/early 2010s, the villainous character of Red Hulk was brought to the Marvel comics universe, to mixed reception. Later on, it was revealed that this character was

> General Thunderbolt Ross, longtime nemesis of the Hulk

and man with an impressive moustache. When Red Hulk was introduced, he had no moustache, and in various appearances, when transforming, his moustache disappears. Why does the moustache disappear instead of just growing with Red Hulk?

Comment: The face swells and the moustache is absorbed

Comment: To make things even muddier, a later, different, red hulk did sport a moustache: https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Robert_Maverick_(Earth-616)